# Sync Hotmail with Android so it recognize read status

Tags: email, hotmail

All the email it pulls are currently unread, it's really annoying, how do I set it up so Hotmail and Android know a email has been read?

Comment: This seems to primarily be a problem on a Galaxy S3.  Are you having this issue w/ a different Android phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the built-in Android mail client doesn't sync read status with Hotmail.

Have you tried the [official Hotmail client](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hotmail.Z7)? It does seem to support most of Hotmail's more advanced features.

Comment: Yes, this is what I use now.  The interface is not the most convinent, but at least it works.